# zend jquery ajax output correct values that relate to selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

My goal is to display the correct information that corresponds to the selected value when the user selects a person. For example, if the user selects the first person (which is Paul), I want to display the correct states and visits values that correspond with Paul.

Also, if a user adds multiple visits to a person, I just want to display all the states they have visited.

As of right now, I display all my information through the selected value of the input. I'm confused and lost how to approach this problem.

```
    // populate people/states, also person/visit form submit
$(document).ready(function(){
    zendPopulatePeople();
    zendPopulateStates();
    displayPeopleData();
    displayStatesData();
    displayVisitsData();

    $('#addPersonSubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            addPerson();
    });

    $('#addVisitSubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            addVisit();
    });
});

// display People Data
function displayPeopleData()
{
    $("#SelectHumanDropDown").change(function(){
        var selectedPerson = $("#SelectHumanDropDown").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/people/" + selectedPerson,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#PeopleInfo").empty();
                var firstName = data[0]["firstname"];
                var lastName = data[0]["lastname"];
                var food = data[0]["food"];

                $("#PeopleInfo").append(
                "First name: " + firstName +
                "<br> Last name: " + lastName +
                "<br> Favorite food: " + food);
            }
        });
    });
}

//display States Data
function displayStatesData()
{
    $("#SelectHumanDropDown").change(function(){
        var selectedPerson = $("#SelectHumanDropDown").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/states/" + selectedPerson,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#StatesInfo").empty();
                var dataLength = data.length;

                if(dataLength > 0)
                {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item)
                    {
                        var stateName = data[i]["statename"];
                        $("#StatesInfo").append("Visited the State : " + stateName + "<br>");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You need to add a visit");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

//display Visits Data
function displayVisitsData()
{
    $("#SelectHumanDropDown").change(function(){
        var selectedPerson = $("#SelectHumanDropDown").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/visits/" + selectedPerson,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#VisitsInfo").empty();
                var dataLength = data.length;

                if(dataLength > 0)
                {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item)
                    {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                        var dateVisit = data[i]["date_visited"];
                        $("#VisitsInfo").append(" on " + dateVisit);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You need to add a visit");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

//populate zendPeople's dropdowns
function zendPopulatePeople()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"api/people",
        dataType:"json",
        success : function(data)
        {
            $("#SelectHumanDropDown option").not("#personOptions").remove();
            $("#humanNameDropDown option").not("#personOptions").remove();

            $.each(data, function(i,item)
            {
                $("#SelectHumanDropDown").append("<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].firstname + "</option>");
                $("#humanNameDropDown").append("<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].firstname + "</option>");
            });
        },
        error : function(data)
        {
            console.log('failed');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

//populate zendState's dropdown
function zendPopulateStates()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"api/states",
        dataType:"json",
        success : function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i,item)
            {
                $("#stateNameDropDown").append("<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].statename + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
}

//Add person to database
function addPerson()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/people",
        data: $("#personForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("You have added a person");
            console.log(data);
            console.log($("#personForm").serialize());
            zendPopulatePeople();
            displayPeopleData();
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            alert("Please fill out all inputs");
            console.log(data);
            console.log($("#personForm").serialize());
        }
    });
}

//Add visit to database
function addVisit()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/visits",
        data: $("#visitForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("You have added a visit");
            console.log(data);
            console.log($("#visitForm").serialize());
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert("Please fill out all inputs");
            console.log(data);
            console.log($("#visitForm").serialize());
        }
    });
}
```

So this is my init.php (database):

```
    <?php

//zf configure db-adapter "adapter=PDO_MYSQL&dbname=[myDB]&host=[localhost]&username=[root]&password=[root]" -s development

// Define variables. 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "myDB";

//Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);

// Check connection
if(!$connection){
die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
else{
    echo "Connection successfully \n";
}

// Drop database
$dropDB = "DROP DATABASE myDB";

// Check drop database
if($connection->query($dropDB) === TRUE){
     echo "Database myDB was successfully dropped \n";
} else {
    echo "Error dropping database: \n" . $connection->error;
}

//Create Database called "myDB"
$db = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDB";

//Check Datebase
if($connection->query($db) === TRUE){
    echo "Database created successfully \n";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: \n" . $connection->error;
}

// Select Database
$connection->select_db($database);

//Create States Table
$statesTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS States
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
stateabb varchar(2) NOT NULL,
statename varchar(40) NOT NULL
)";

// Create People Table
$peopleTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
lastname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
food varchar(40) NOT NULL
)";

// Create Visit Table
$visitTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Visits
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p_id INT(40) NOT NULL,
s_id INT(40) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES People(id),
FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES States(id),
date_visited varchar(40) NOT NULL
)";

//Check States Table
if($connection->query($statesTable) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "States Table created successfully \n";
}
else
{
    echo "States Table wasn't created \n" . $connection->error;
}

//Check People Table
if($connection->query($peopleTable) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "People Table created successfully \n";
}
else
{
    echo "People Table wasn't created \n" . $connection->error;
}

//Check Visit Table
if($connection->query($visitTable) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "Visit Table created successfully \n";
}
else
{
    echo "Visit Table wasn't created \n" . $connection->error;
}

// Insert data into states table
$insertData = " INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('LA', 'Louisiana');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('FL', 'Florida');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('TX', 'Texas');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('NM', 'New Mexico');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('ID', 'Idaho');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('IA', 'Iowa');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('ME', 'Maine');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('NV', 'Nevada');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('NY', 'New York');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO States (stateabb, statename) 
                VALUES ('UT', 'Utah');";

// Insert data into people table
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, food) 
                VALUES ('Paul', 'Chu', 'Rice');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, food) 
                VALUES ('Chui', 'Chu', 'Steak');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, food) 
                VALUES ('Pandalord', 'Chu', 'Cookies');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, food) 
                VALUES ('LordBabyPanda', 'Chu', 'Milk');";

// Insert data into Visits table
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO Visits (p_id, s_id, date_visited) 
                VALUES ('1', '1', '1994/07/14');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO Visits (p_id, s_id, date_visited) 
                VALUES ('1', '2', '1994/07/14');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO Visits (p_id, s_id, date_visited) 
                VALUES ('2', '10', '1994/07/14');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO Visits (p_id, s_id, date_visited) 
                VALUES ('3', '9', '1994/07/14');";
$insertData .= "INSERT INTO Visits (p_id, s_id, date_visited) 
                VALUES ('4', '7', '1994/07/14');";

// Check stateData in table
if($connection->multi_query($insertData) === TRUE)
{
    $lastID = $connection->insert_id;
    echo "insertData create successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $lastID . "\n";
}

else
{
    echo "Error: \n" . $connection->error;
}

//Close Connection
$connection->close();
?>
```

Please and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just create an api endpoint that collects all the data you want to display? This would be much simpler than sending one request for each type of data (person, state and visit).

Comment: @Quagaar , Hey, thanks for the suggestion, and I actually did it that way before I saw this comment. Yeah, on my mapper, I made a whole new function and used sql to inner join and grab the information I wanted. Then I just put it into an array and echo json_encode and boom, I got what I actually wanted. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved my problem by doing it on the backend and shot back the correct info into an array and then just echo json_encode.

```
    public function getPeopleVisits($id)
{
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $database = "myDB";
  $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
  if(!$connection){
  die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
  $connection->select_db($database);
  $sql = "SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, s.statename, p.food, v.date_visited
    FROM Visits v
    INNER JOIN People p ON v.p_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN States s ON v.s_id = s.id
    WHERE v.p_id =" . $id;
  $query = mysqli_query ($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

  $id = $row["id"];
  $firstName = $row["firstname"];
  $lastName = $row["lastname"];
  $foodName = $row["food"];
  $stateName = $row["statename"];
  $dateVisit = $row["date_visited"];
  $resultArray[] =
  [
      'id'            => $id,
      'firstname'     => $firstName,
      'lastname'      => $lastName,
      'food'          => $foodName,
      'statename'     => $stateName,
      'date_visited'  => $dateVisit
  ];
  echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```